# Restore SharePoint 2010 Site Collection to SharePoint 2013?

Tags: site-collection, restore

We are considering moving a single site collection from a SharePoint 2010 box to SharePoint 2013 to take advantage of the difference in licensing for external anonymous users.

Can you do a backup and restore from a SP 2010 site collection to SP 2013 and then have this site collection run in 2010 compatibility mode?

I've read that the recommended way for upgrading is by the database detach/attach method, but with just that one site collection in mind, we were wondering if this is also a valid way to move to a SharePoint 2013 server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it won't work that way.  You should do a backup and restore in your SP 2010 environment and put the site collection into it's own database.  Then do a sql backup and restore of the database into the 2013 farm and content db attach it for it to upgrade correctly.